# map is not a function returning div inside ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm trying to do a little react app pulling some uniswap crypto data for my own UI just for fun, I've grabbed some data with a graphql query and I'm trying to render it out on the condition that its loaded which I get from a ternary operator in my functional component.

when I try this in multiple combinations, I just get the error that `allTokenData.map is not a function`

I have included my component below and I have notated where my mapping function is trying to pull data from the array I get back from graphql, since I'm getting data I'm sure I'm just mixing something up with the mapping syntax :/

here is a snippet of the data I'm grabbing for reference logged in the console, any help is appreciated

[image]

```
function CoinData(props) {

  //fetch whichever coin we want to add
  const NEWCOIN_QUERY = gql`
  query tokens($tokenAddress: Bytes!) {
    tokens(where: { id: $tokenAddress }) {
      derivedETH
      totalLiquidity
    }
  }
`;
  

  const { loading: ethLoading, data: ethPriceData } = useQuery(ETH_PRICE_QUERY);
  const { loading: allLoading, data: allTokenData } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_TOKENS);
  const { loading: coinLoading, data: coindata } = useQuery(NEWCOIN_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      tokenAddress: props.parentState.newcoins!== '' ? props.parentState.newcoins.toString() : '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',
    },
  });

  const coinPriceInEth = coindata && coindata.tokens[0].derivedETH;
  const coinTotalLiquidity = coindata && coindata.tokens[0].totalLiquidity;
  const ethPriceInUSD = ethPriceData && ethPriceData.bundles[0].ethPrice;
  console.log(props.parentState.newcoins)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        coin price:{" "}
        {ethLoading || coinLoading
          ? "Loading token data..."
          : "$" +
            // parse responses as floats and fix to 2 decimals
            (parseFloat(coinPriceInEth) * parseFloat(ethPriceInUSD)).toFixed(2)}
      </div>
      <div>
        Coin total liquidity:{" "}
        {coinLoading ? "Loading token data...": parseFloat(coinTotalLiquidity).toFixed(0)}
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>

            <div>
//////////////////////////////////////////----map function////////////////////////////
            {allLoading ? "Loading token data...": 

                  <div>
                        {allTokenData.map((token, index) => (
                          <p key={index}> {token.id} SYN: {token.symbol}</p>
                        ))}
                  </div>
            }
//////////////////////////////////////////----map function////////////////////////////
            </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the function `useQuery` is async. Therefore, `allTokenData` can be `undefined` or `null` (depends on the implementation)

Comment: I suspect that `allTokenData` is not an array. Test this with a `React.useEffect(() => console.log(allTokenData), [allTokenData]);`.

Comment: useQuery(QUERY_ALL_TOKENS); where is that query that you pass to useQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe allTokenData.tokens.map.

Comment: this actually was the correct format to use in my case thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

It is because allTokenData is an object.

const {tokens} = allTokenData

```
{tokens.map((token, index) => (
                          <p key={index}> {token.id} SYN: {token.symbol}</p>
                        ))}
```